# Convert an Object to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, oop

I am working with [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) and since I don't believe it is possible to sort object details, I was wondering how to go about converting my [Object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) to an [Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php), so that sorting can be possible.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the WP function [get_categories();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

**The complete content of $category is:**

```
$category->term_id
$category->name
$category->slug
$category->term_group
$category->term_taxonomy_id
$category->taxonomy
$category->description
$category->parent
$category->count
$category->cat_ID
$category->category_count
$category->category_description
$category->cat_name
$category->category_nicename
$category->category_parent
```

Comment: What object do you have?

Comment: No, I mean what is the structure of your object?  What data does it have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the object is not too complex (in terms of nesting) you can cast the class to an array:

```
$example = new StdClass();
$example->foo = 'bar';

var_dump((array) $example);
```

outputs:

```
array(1) { ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" }
```

However this will only convert the base level. If you have nested objects such as

```
$example = new StdClass();
$example->foo = 'bar';
$example->bar = new StdClass();
$example->bar->blah = 'some value';

var_dump((array) $example);
```

Then only the base object will be cast to an array.

```
array(2) { 
  ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar" 
  ["bar"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { 
    ["blah"]=> string(10) "some value" 
  }
}
```

In order to go deeper, you would have to use recursion. There is a good example of an object to array conversion [here](http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/567/php-recursively-convert-an-object-to-an-array).

Comment: I missed your link as I posted my function, didn't mean to step on toes. +1

Answer (score 10):

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind extending the answer bit more for fellow programmers.

Answer (score 5):

as simple as

```
$array = (array)$object;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Comment: I have tried $array = (array)get_categories(); but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

To convert an object to array you can use `get_object_vars()` ([PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)):

```
$categoryVars = get_object_vars($category)
```

Comment: While, this answers OP, it will fail if there is an array at base level and then objects inside it or further reccursive.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @galen

```
<?php 
    $categories = get_categories(); 
    $array = (array)$categories;  
?>
```

Comment: Just so you know, this method does not work with get_categories(); I have used the recursive object to array conversion function in the link posted by @Andy

Answer (score 1):

To convert the entire object and all it's properties to arrays, you can use this clunky function I've had kicking around for a while:

```
function object_to_array($object)
{
    if (is_array($object) OR is_object($object))
    {
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($object as $key => $value)
        { 
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value); 
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Tr8rktjN

But for your example, with that data, you should be able to just cast to array as others have already said.

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

Comment: [It should work fine](http://codepad.org/YXd8aqvF), try assigning `get_categories()` to a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

A less clunky way might be:

```
function objectToArray($object) 
{ 
    if(!is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ))
    { 
        return $object; 
    } 
    if(is_object($object) ) 
    { 
        $object = get_object_vars( $object ); 
    } 
    return array_map('objectToArray', $object ); 
}
```

(Sourced from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?438748-convert-object-to-array)
Note, if you'd like this as a method in a class, change the last line to:

```
return array_map(array($this, __FUNCTION__), $object );
```